# Your file couldn’t be accessed It may have been moved, edited, or deleted. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: html, css

i want to link the anchor to other file in my project but it dont work.
code.

```
 <a href="form.html" class="btn medilife-appoint-btn ml-30" style="text-align:center; text-decoration:none;background-color: #006cff; color: white; border: 1px solid black;">patiente Login</a>
              <a href="new/team.html" class="btn1" style="position: relative; left: 50px;text-decoration: none; background-color: #006cff;border: 1px solid black;color: white; border-radius: 2px;" >Doctor Login</a>
```

Comment: Your question could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as code, citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your question is correct and are able to answer. You can find more information on how to write good questions in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

debes validar si el archivo que buscas se encuentra en la ruta correcta.

Comment: Yeah it is......

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).